# Вопрос по синтаксису для Телеграм бота

Tags: javascript, node.js

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, что делать! Пишу сейчас бота, и условно абзацы его сообщений у меня в VS code прописаны следующим образом:[image: изначальный код - см картинку №1]

Мой вопрос заключается в том, что мне надо сделать, чтобы добавить следующий абзац в ЭТО ЖЕ сообщение от бота, чтобы получилось так: [image: изображение чата с ботом - см.картинку №2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте обычный `\n` для разделения сообщения на абзацы

Comment: благодарю))))))